# How to configure ABI specific C and CPP flags in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, build.gradle, abi, oculusquest

I've written an OpenXr Android NDK application that runs on the Oculus Quest 2 and the original Oculus Quest (we'll call that one "Quest 1"). I've recently added some enhancements and in doing so find that I need to be able to compile the common C and CPP sources differently for the two different Quest models. In my app's C and CPP code, I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
#ifdef QUEST_2
    do some Quest 2 specfic code
#endif

#ifdef QUEST_1
    do some Quest 1 specific code
#endif
```

So what I'd like to do is specify that for Quest 2s, the gcc and g++ invocations to compile my app's source go something like this:

```
gcc -DQUEST_2 myapp.c
g++ -DQUEST_2 myapp.cpp
```

While the compilation for Quest 1s be something like this:

```
gcc -DQUEST_1 myapp.c
g++ -DQUEST_1 myapp.cpp
```

The Quest 2 uses the arm64-v8a ABI while the Quest 1 uses the armeabi-v7a ABI. Both these ABIs are listed in my app's build.gradle like so:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
            cmake {
                cppFlags ''
                // version "3.22.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My build.gradle also supports 2 different product flavors:

```
productFlavors {
    OpenGLES {
        dimension 'api'
        applicationIdSuffix '.opengles'
        externalNativeBuild.cmake.cppFlags '-DDEFAULT_GRAPHICS_PLUGIN_OPENGLES'

        resValue "string", "app_name", "mirror_ball (OpenGL ES)"
    }
    Vulkan {
        dimension 'api'
        applicationIdSuffix '.vulkan'
        externalNativeBuild.cmake.cppFlags '-DDEFAULT_GRAPHICS_PLUGIN_VULKAN'

        resValue "string", "app_name", "mirror_ball (Vulkan)"
    }
}
```

And sure enough depending on whether I build for OpenGLES or Vulkan, the compilers get invoked with either -DDEFAULT_GRAPHICS_PLUGIN_OPENGLES or -DDEFAULT_GRAPHICS_PLUGIN_VULKAN, respectively, so it seems possible to specify product flavor specific C and CPP compiler flags.

But how to I get different C and CPP compiler flags for the two different ABIs?

Thanks

============================================================

update based on Michael's comment:

I tried out the ANDROID_ABI solution. It's progress, but there's still an issue. I made this addition to my app's CMakeLists.txt:

```
$ diff ~/opengl/monado/mirror_ball_backups/save006/CMakeLists.txt CMakeLists.txt
33a34,35
>     string(REGEX REPLACE "\\-" "" ANDROID_ABI_NO_DASHES ${ANDROID_ABI})
>     add_definitions(-D${ANDROID_ABI_NO_DASHES})
```

The goal of the above being removing the dashes from armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a since to a C preprocessor those look like terms with minus operators in them. Then in my cpp code I added this:

```
const char *androidTargetName =

#if defined(armeabiv7a)
            "armeabiv7a"
#elif defined(arm64v8a)
            "arm64v8a"
#else
            "nonandroid"
#endif
        ;

Log::Write(Log::Level::Info, Fmt("androidTargetName = %s", androidTargetName));
```

Problem is I get the same log output on both Quest 1 and Quest 2.

On Quest 2, good:

```
03-24 17:25:17.333  4478  4512 V mirror_ball: [17:25:17.333][Info   ] androidTargetName = arm64v8a
```

On Quest 1, should be armeabiv7a:

```
03-24 17:49:53.140  4242  4275 V mirror_ball: [17:49:53.140][Info   ] androidTargetName = arm64v8a
```

The app runs on the Quest 1 as well as it ever does, so its presumably getting the armeabiv7a build.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks again.

============================================================

Another update:

Well paraphrasing Alice, this rat hole just gets curiouser and curiouser. First I tried swapping the order of the listed abiFilters in build.gradle from this:

```
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
```

to this:

```
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
```

This results in the exact same behavior as before on both Quest 1 and Quest 2. Both show:

```
03-27 17:59:42.728  4956  4992 V mirror_ball: [17:59:42.728][Info   ] androidTargetName = arm64v8a
```

Then I tried removing the 'arm64-v8a' option from abiFilters:

```
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
```

When I build this code on Android Studio with my Quest 1 attached and run it, I get this in the logcat output:

```
03-27 18:37:29.163  4377  4408 V mirror_ball: [18:37:29.163][Info   ] androidTargetName = armeabiv7a
```

So that work around works in that I can build code that is Quest 1 specific. Not ideal, since it would mean I'd have to build and publish two APKs, one with just support for Quest 1 and a second with just support for Quest 2 in order to support my app on both target systems.

But then I see this little ditty in my build log:

```
[CXX5202] This app only has 32-bit [armeabi-v7a] native libraries. Beginning August 1, 2019 Google Play store requires that all apps that include native libraries must provide 64-bit versions. For more information, visit https://g.co/64-bit-requirement
```

Which, assuming Oculus/Meta follows the same rule on their store, means that I can't publish an APK of my app for just Quest 1. So it would seem the only way going forward to support my app on Quest 1 and Quest 2 is to determine which target the app is running on at run time, rather than build time, and thus include run time support for both targets in both of the Quest 1 and Quest 2 versions of the app. This despite the fact that separate binaries for the two target systems have to be built and packaged into a single APK anyway since Quest 1 uses a 32 bit processor and Quest 2 is 64 bit.

All in the name of planned obsolescence. Thanks Google.

Comment: You could do this in your CMakeLists.txt file. I.e. conditionally adding compile options based on the value of [`ANDROID_ABI`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#android_abi).

Comment: +1 for doing this in CMakeLists.txt. Setting cflags or cppflags in your build.gradle can override default behaviors in surprising ways, e.g. https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1693